# RegEx for string starts with number and followed by + character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want a regular expression for such inputs:

```
1+2
3
1+22+3
```

But If I write following inputs then it should not allow. Such as;

```
+1+2
1+
a+1+b+c
12+
```

The string must start with number and then followed by only `+` character. But After the + character, it has to be any number.
I tried this `[^0-9][^+]?` but İt deletes the `+` sign at the start with the regex I wrote, but there is a problem. While deleting the `+` character, it also removes the number next to it. This event keeps repeating.

How can I do this?

Comment: Usually something like `^[0-9]+(?:\+[0-9]+)*$` would work. Note that for `.NET`, if I recall correctly, you'd rather be specific about the numbers to avoid numbers from other languages unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: @JvdV You could post it :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I'm unsure since it seems the other answer is rather popular. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @JvdV The posted answer might be a good answer, but note that it gives partial matches, and in the repetition only matches a single digit. https://regex101.com/r/IsKBGJ/1 Without the anchors you might also write your pattern as `(?<!\S)[0-9]+(?:\+[0-9]+)*(?!\S)`

Answer (score 6):

Please try :

```
\d+(\+\d)*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hfqmYr/2

Where:

\d -> Matches with any digit

+ -> Matches a symbol one or more times

* -> Matching a symbol 0 or many times

Comment: You need + instead of * on digits for 1 or more to cover minimal binary op expression.

Comment: Agree!! Thanks @vendettamit

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like you can use:

```
^[0-9]+(?:\+[0-9]+)*$
```

This is to allow the mentioned sample data and discard those you don't want to allow. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fUQIba/1). The pattern matches:

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ Digits (ASCII).
- `(?:\+[0-9]+)*` - 0+ Times a non-capture group to allow for a literal plus followed by 1+ digits (ASCII).
- `$` - End line anchor.

As per my knowledge `.NET` requires you to explicitly mention these ASCII digits to avoid matching numbers from other languages (unless specified otherwise using [ECMAScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) options).